# Getting the grandparent directory of the current code

Tags: python, functional-programming, file-system

I have this example:

```
from os.path import dirname, realpath
dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath(__file__)))
```

And the chained `dirname()` applications look a bit odd to me. Is there a way to improve my code? There is of course something like [Better Function Composition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264406/better-function-composition-in-python), but that seems too complicated to me.

Maybe, some solution with function composition "[∘](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)" would be better?

```
reduce(∘, [dirname] * 3)(realpath(__file__))
```

But that doesn't look any better.

Do you have any ideas for this concrete example?

Comment: That 'Better Function Composition in Python' is _way_ simpler than your `reduce` example.

Comment: I don't see any working code to review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be short one, but as we all know, in most cases, "*explicit is better than implicit*".

Indeed, the second one is ugly and not easily understandable at the first sight. Doing something like this might be better:

```
from os.path import dirname, realpath

filepath = realpath(__file__)

dir_of_file = dirname(filepath)
parent_dir_of_file = dirname(dir_of_file)
parents_parent_dir_of_file = dirname(parent_dir_of_file)
```

OFC that's in no way simpler than your first solution, altough it might be clear what the end-result will look like.

More, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150750/8605514):

> `os.path.abspath` doesn't validate anything, so if we're already
>   appending strings to `__file__` there's no need to bother with
>   `dirname`. Just treat `__file__` as a directory and start climbing:
>
> ```
> # climb to __file__'s parent's parent:
> os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../../")
> ```

Climbing more than two levels starts to get ridiculous.

> But, since we know how many levels to climb, we could clean this up
>   with a simple little function:
>
> ```
> uppath = lambda _path, n: os.sep.join(_path.split(os.sep)[:-n])
>
> # __file__ = "/aParent/templates/blog1/page.html"
> >>> uppath(__file__, 1)
> '/aParent/templates/blog1'
> >>> uppath(__file__, 2)
> '/aParent/templates'
> >>> uppath(__file__, 3)
> '/aParent'
> ```